# Before submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to use `HTML5` inputs (type="email", etc.), but I need also show own error message, which I can style in CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '<div>Email must be valid.</div>';
   return false;
}
```

```css
#message > div {
  font-family: Open Sans, Arial;
  font-size: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="email" required />
   <button>Send</button>
</form>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Does anyone know how to run a my own script before HTML5 validation? I can think of only onclick button event and after hit enter, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do your own validation add `novalidate` attribute to form to prevent html5 internal validation done by browser

```
<form id="myForm" novalidate>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use various JS events: [onChange](https://api.jquery.com/change/), [onKeyDown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) etc.